# Many to Many relationship in redbeanphp not working

Tags: php, redbean

A company can have many sectors it operates in, e.g an engineering company may operate in Structures, Robotics, Electronics etc etc...

I have a table of preset sectors:

```
 $sectors = array('structural', 'robotics', 'environment'); // shortened as too long to post here

foreach ($sectors as $sector){
  $s = R::dispense( 'sector' );
  $s->name = $sector;
  R::store($s);  
}
```

I have a company table and I want to assign one or more sectors to a company when I select them from a form:

```
  $sectors = array_keys($_POST['sectors']);

  foreach($sectors as $sector){ 
    echo $sector;
    //$s = R::findOne( 'sector',' name = ? ', "$sector" );
    $s  = R::findOne( 'sector', ' name = ? ', array($sector) );
    $company->sharedSectorList[] = $s); // seems to stop working here   
  }  

  // other stuff goes here
  $id = R::store( $company );
```

I have the following at the top of my page:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, no error is displayed, it just says HTTP Error 500, currently unable to handle this request. It seems to stop working at the ->sharedSectorList[] line.

Comment: arrr it was the ), I think...